# Torrent Library for C++, Windows

Tags: c++, windows, p2p, bittorrent

I'm looking for a library which allows my C++ application (run in Windows) to download torrents. I can't, however, find any out there.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/

It is used in [Halite](http://www.binarynotions.com/halite-bittorrent-client/), which is a pretty good client :)

The library has a BSD license, and seems to be used in quite a few clients:

http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/projects.html

Comment: Dead links to library.

Comment: @Prof.Falken: You have my permission to fix it? Grumble grumble collaborative website grumble grumble... (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libtorrent - some of the links are still up. I imagine their site is just down for some reason)

Comment: Hehe, I was half hoping you knew something more than me. Anyway, it seems the domain was not paid for in time. 91.201.63.153   rasterbar.com
91.201.63.153   www.rasterbar.com

Comment: ah, b2 boost=source runtime-link=static -sBOOST=C:\boost_1_54_0

Answer (score 4):

[Qt has an example: torrent client.](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/network-torrent.html)